# HPUX 11i v3 Auditing to a syslog server - Configuration

Tags: syslog, hp-ux, audit

I had trouble setting up auditing on our HPUX system and sending the same to a SIEM solution as a multiline log. 
The issue was that audsys writes the log to binary files and I need it to be setup in such a way audisp would convert it to a text file and send the same to our syslog server at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup the /etc/rc.config.d/auditing file as below

```
AUDITING=1
PRI_AUDFILE=/var/.audit/audfile1
PRI_SWITCH=10000
SEC_AUDFILE=/var/.audit/audfile2
SEC_SWITCH=10000
AUDEVENT_ARGS1=" -P -F -r Remotesyslog"
AUDEVENT_ARGS2=""
AUDEVENT_ARGS3=""
AUDEVENT_ARGS4=""
AUDOMON_ARGS=" -p 20 -t 1 -w 90"
```

I then created a custom profile in /etc/audit/audit_site.conf

```
#Custom Auditing File
# Audit self auditing admin commands, logins and execve calls
PROFILE Remotesyslog= SELFAUD_EVENT admin, EVENT login, execve, execv
```

I created the below in /var/.audit

```
1) A folder "remotelogs"
2) A script "remotelogs.sh"
```

Content of the script file is as below

```
NOW=$(/usr/bin/date +"%Y%m%d%H%M")

if /usr/bin/audsys | grep -q audfile1; then
  /usr/bin/audsys -c /var/.audit/audfile2 -s 100000
  /usr/bin/audisp /var/.audit/audfile1 > /var/.audit/remotelogs/remotelogs.log.${NOW}
  sleep 5
  /usr/contrib/bin/gzip /var/.audit/remotelogs/remotelogs.log.${NOW}
  rm -r /var/.audit/audfile1
else
  /usr/bin/audsys -c /var/.audit/audfile1 -s 100000
  /usr/bin/audisp /var/.audit/audfile2 > /var/.audit/remotelogs/remotelogs.log.${NOW}
  sleep 5
  /usr/contrib/bin/gzip /var/.audit/remotelogs/remotelogs.log.${NOW}
  rm -r /var/.audit/audfile2
fi
```

Basically what the script does is check which is the current audit trail and then switches to the next audit trail, dumps the contents of the current audit trail to a text file with the timestamp appended to it. It waits for 5 seconds to give time to dump the contents and then compresses the text file and then removes the contents of the current audit trail.

To run this at regular intervals (every 3 minutes), I scheduled a cronjob for the same in crontab as follows

```
3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,59 * * * * /var/.audit/remotelogs.sh
```

Also I added another cronjob to remove logs older than 3 days as follows

```
00 00 * * * find /var/.audit/remotelogs/* -mtime +3 | xargs rm
```